# How to create a new FBA user programatically using VS 2010?

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, forms-authentication

I am looking to create a new FBA user (explicitly) in the membership db using the membershipuser create user programatically.  The purpose is to test permissions using the spfarm account.

What is the simplest way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out below articles:

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/programmatically-create-users-in-aspnet.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es.aspx